# How to change mailx?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-wheezy, email

I am having a problem in my VMs.

I used the same template (Debian 7min) in OpenVZ, but for whatever reason those two are using a different mailx. I have a small script which I use to send statusmails:

```
    mailx -v -s "$subject" -S smtp=$smtphost -S from="$mailfrom" -S smtp-auth-user=$smtpuser \
 -S smtp-auth-password=$smtppwd $emailto </dev/null
```

It works find on one server, the other one give me an error message 'unknown command -S'.

Ok, I know mailx is just a virtual package, and I usually install bsd-mailx, but both server show they are setup identical

ls -al /etc/alternatives/ma*

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb  9 20:07 /etc/alternatives/mailx -> /usr/bin/bsd-mailx
```

dpkg --get-selections | grep  mail

```
bsd-mailx                   install
fetchmail                   install
procmail                    install
rmail                       install
sendmail                    install
sendmail-base                   install
sendmail-bin                    install
sendmail-cf                 install
sendmail-doc                    install
```

Problem is, mailx like never supports any kind of version info, so mailx --help or --version just says 'unknown option' - so I cant even figure out what 'version' of mailx it is

This is output from server 1

```
mailx: illegal option -- -
Usage: mailx -eiIUdEFntBDNHRV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users
```

this is output from server 2

```
mailx: invalid option -- '-'
usage: mailx [-dEIinv] [-a header] [-b bcc-addr] [-c cc-addr] [-s subject] to-addr ...
             [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mailx [-dEIiNnv] -f [name]
       mailx [-dEIiNnv] [-u user]
```

Clearly not idential. Any helps how I can 'get' the mailx from server 1 to server 2? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the server1 you have heilroom-mailx i.e. `/etc/alternatives/mailx -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx`, the second server uses `bsd-mailx`.

Do `apt-get install heirloom-mailx` on both servers if you want to have mailx from server1.

After installing, server should automatically use heirloom as mailx, if not do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set mailx /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
```

Comment: On Debian Stretch before running the above command, you need to register the mailx alternative using the command: `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mailx mailx /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx 10`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from @darek and @nadir-latif `/usr/bin/mail` is also an alternative and is a slave of the `mailx` alternative, from checking Wheezy/Jessie installations the `heirloom-mailx` priority was 60 so to install use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mailx mailx /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx \
60 --slave /usr/bin/mail mail /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx \
--slave /usr/share/man/man1/mail.1.gz mail.1.gz \
/usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz --slave \
/usr/share/man/man1/mailx.1.gz mailx.1.gz \
/usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
```

which will allow setting both the `mail` and `mailx` alternatives.  On Stretch the `mail.mailutils` has a priority of 30 and from the man page

> When a link group is in automatic mode, the alternatives pointed to by members of the group will be those which have the highest priority.

so if you use the priority of `60` and you have it set to automatic you will not need to explicitly set the alternative, otherwise as @darek states use

```
sudo update-alternatives --set mailx /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
```